# Locking a GNU-screen session after x minutes of non-use on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnu-screen

I have a couple of services running in a GNU-screen session on top of Bash. Because one of the services contain sensitive data I have to constantly either close the terminal completely or lock the screen session using `C^a X`. Sometimes I forget to close or lock this window when leaving my desk which is not good so I want to know.

How can I get GNU-screen to automatically lock the window after XX minutes of non-use or get Bash/terminal emulator to execute the `C^a X` command after a time interval? I am aware I can lock the screen using the window manager, but I would like this in addition just in case.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `idle` option from screen:

> idle [timeout [cmd args]]
>
> Sets  a command that is run after the specified number of seconds
>   inac‐ tivity is reached. This command will normally be the "blanker" 
>   command to  create  a  screen blanker, but it can be any screen
>   command.  If no command is specified, only the timeout is set. A
>   timeout  of  zero  (ot the  special  timeout  off)  disables  the 
>   timer.  If no arguments are given, the current settings are displayed.

Comment: Just to clearify: To get screen to lock itself after for example 4 minutes you would add a line in your ~/.screenrc file containing the following `idle 300 lockscreen`.

Comment: @Mogget: You should post an answer, because without your comment the answer is not usable.

Answer (score 2):

@problemofficer mentioned I should put an answer in this thread since withouth the comment I made, the answer made to this post is not complete.

To make a screen session automatically lock itself after for example 5 minutes do the following; Add a line in your ~/.screenrc file containing the following.

```
idle 300 lockscreen
```

Any current screen sessions has to be re